# Doesn't Publishing Pages get security-trimmed?

Tags: navigation, security-trimming

I am testing the SharePoint navigation with this setup.

```
Root-Site `All have access`
----SubSite1 `UserA does not have access`
--------SubSite1/Pages/default.aspx `inherits permissions from SubSite1`
```

If I create a heading or link in the Navigation Settings which refers to SubSite1 it will not be shown to UserA, which is correct behaviour.

But if I create a heading or link in the Navigation Settings to SubSite1/Pages/default.aspx it will be shown to the UserA

Why is this? Is this a shortcoming of SharePoint? In that case how do I make PortalSiteMapProvider to also security-trim pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long time of no answer I kinda managed to answer my own question, which might be of help to future developers.

ACL Caches the permissions. My problem was that when I made a navigationlink to a page and the chagned the permission of that page afterwards the problem could be seen.

But if I first made changes to the permission and then made a link to this page, everything worked. However, a IISReset also fixes the issue since it wipes the ACL Cache.